# Learning resources for the WPF/XAML Illiterate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Okay, I know this has been asked before, but the solutions to previously asked questions haven't helped me. I've never made an app in XAML/WPF before and I feel really stupid when I try to learn it, but with the release of Windows 8 release preview, it is looking like I *have to* learn it.

Are there any resources that you would recommend to somebody as stupid as myself?

Thank you all

Specifically, my main trouble is not knowing how to *properly* position/align things on a Window in XAML. I find it extremely difficult to understand. I'm used to Docking things, and so forth, but I don't see any dock options for XAML. I'm also used to absolute positioning - or positioning by relativity from the edge of the window/screen - but that way doesn't work in XAML from what I've tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Specifically, my main trouble is not knowing how to properly position/align things on a Window in XAML. I find it extremely difficult to understand. I'm used to Docking things, and so forth, but I don't see any dock options for XAML. I'm also used to absolute positioning - or positioning by relativity from the edge of the window/screen - but that way doesn't work in XAML from what I've tried.

The key to this is understanding how the [Layout System](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745058.aspx) works in Xaml.

Once you understand the difference in the overall approach to layout, then understanding the individual [panels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754152.aspx) and [alignment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751709.aspx) make most things approachable.

The main difference is that the *container* typically handles the layout of the children.  Instead of docking or aligning an element, you typically have the parent handle the layout, and use attached properties (ie: `Grid.Row`) to position the child within the parent.

This makes it far simpler to handle resolution independence, though it takes a bit of getting used to at first.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of `Grid`, `Canvas`, `StackPanel`, or `WrapPanel` (among others) to help position things.

It's usually a combination of the above controls, but the most common method I've seen is using the `Grid` to create rows and columns, and positioning your controls inside them.

I would recommend Josh Smith's tutorial http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18251/A-Guided-Tour-of-WPF-Part-2-Layout

Answer (score 1):

For an in-depth learning resource, check out the Pro WPF in C# 2010 book: [http://www.amazon.com/Pro-WPF-2010-Presentation-Foundation/dp/1430272058/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1339377007&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430272058)

It includes several chapters on elements and how positioning works. I've found it to be extremely helpful and would recommend it.

If you're not interested in reading something so lengthy, I would recommend viewing the example code on MSDN for different layout controls, such as the `Grid`, `StackPanel`, and `DockPanel`.